# Struggling to get a Makefile running with separate header and source files directory

Tags: c, makefile

I'm really struggling to get this Makefile to run correctly. The current error I'm getting is:

```
make: Iheader: Command not found
Makefile: 18: recipe for target 'object/fcfs.o' failed
make: [object/fcfs.o] Error 127 (ignored)
Iheader -MMD -MP -c -o object/sjf.o src/sjf.c
```

And then this error repeats over for each implementation file. I'm still new to building my own make files and I feel like this is a simple error that I'm missing. I've tried googling and none of the solutions I've found so far have worked for me.

```
source
|__header
|    |__fcfs.h
|    |__hpf.h
|    |__rr.h
|    |__sjf.h
|
|__object
|
|__src
|    |__fcfs.c
|    |__hpf.c
|    |__main.c
|    |__rr.c
|    |__sjf.c
|
|__Makefile
```

Makefile:

```
INC_DIR   := header
SRC_DIR   := src
OBJ_DIR   := object

CC        := gcc
CPPFLAGS  := -I$(INC_DIR) -MMD -MP

SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
DEPS    := $(wildcard $(OBJ_DIR)/*.d)

.PHONY: clean

main: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CPPFLAGS) -c $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

clean: ; $(RM) $(DEPS) $(OBJECTS)

-include $(DEPS)

$(MAKEFILE_LIST): ;
%.h: ;
%:: %,v
%:: RCS/%,v
%:: RCS/%
%:: s.%
%:: SCCS/s.%
```

My main.c is including all header files and each of the implementation files contains an include to their respective header.

Comment: where is OUTPUT_OPTION defined?

Comment: It's a GNU make variable

Comment: This line: `$(CPPFLAGS) -c $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<` is missing a leading: `$(CC) `

Comment: This line: $(OBJECTS): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c would be better written as: $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c $(OBJECTS)/%.d because all the needed object files will be created due to the 'main' target has the list of object files as a dependency and it also needs to list the related dependancy file

Comment: the last 7 lines of the posted makefile are only needed if make has to extract a file from some configuration control system.  Even then, the format of those lines is a bit off as usually such rules need a call to `co` or `checkout` or similar

Comment: given the posted makefile, the make will be trying to access a `main.h` file (which doesn't exist) and fail on not knowing how to create that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual command to compile the .c files into .o objects is missing. Add `$(CC)` to the recipe:

```
$(OBJECTS): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
    ^^^^^
```

Comment: a good answer, but it is missing listing the related dependancy file,  Without the dependancy filie(s) being listed, they will not be generated nor will an update to a dependancy file cause the related .c file to be re-compiled